# Добавление существующей записи к сущности many-to-many

Tags: entity-framework, mvvm

Code First, Entity Framework 6, зависимость таблиц many-to-many.

есть два класса (привел их сокращенные интерфейсы):

```
public interface IEquipment
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }

    string Description { get; set; }

    List<Material> Materials { get; set; }
}

public interface IMaterial
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }

    string Description { get; set; }

    List<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
}
```

Если в Equipments добавлять новый Materials то все работает как надо. но когда я пытаюсь добавить уже существующий Material то появляются побочные эффекты (зависит от тех примеров которые я смог нагуглить). В основном создается еще пара Equipment и пара Materials, иногда просто ничего не происходит. вот последний вариант кода который я использовал для добавления существующего Material в Equipment:

```
    public void AddExistingMaterial()
    {
        using (EditorPostgresContext<Equipment> db = new EditorPostgresContext<Equipment>())
        {
            if (SelectedMaterial != null)
            {
                var equipment = db.Objects.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == SelectedEquipment.Id);
                equipment.Materials.Add(SelectedMaterial);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Метод срабатывает когда в ListBox пользователь выбирает существующий Material:

```
    public Material SelectedMaterial
    {
        get { return GetValue<Material>(SelectedMaterialProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedMaterialProperty, value);
            AddExistingMaterial();
        }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData SelectedMaterialProperty = RegisterProperty("SelectedMaterial", typeof(Material), null);
```

Собственно вопросы, если что то я делаю не правильно то укажите пожалуйста где.

Если метод вызывается в неправильном месте то как можно реализовать правильное место в условиях MVVM, при выборе из списка уже присутствующих в базе Materials.

Как можно добавить в условиях many-to-many количество Materials для Equipment. Например чтобы создать какой либо equipment нужно 10 materials. как я представляю, самый оптимальный вариант был бы добавить в промежуточную таблицу 3ю колонку где и указывается число 10. Но как это сделать в приведенных выше условиях если таблица создается автоматически фреймворком?

Comment: Собственно проблема в появлении дублирующих записей, как я и предполагал в месте вызова метода, а конкретно в сеттере SelectedMaterial, так как он вызывается два раза при обращении к переменной. Это связано с особенностями работы фреймоврка Catel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте промежуточную таблицу `MaterialEquipment`, которая будет содержать ссылку на левую и правую таблицу. Если для `Equipment` требуется материал в некотором количестве, то можно добавить еще один столбец `count`

---

**DatabaseFirst:**

```
CREATE TABLE [MaterialEquipment](
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [IdMaterial] INT NOT NULL,
    [IdEquipment] INT NOT NULL,
    [Count] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [MaterialEquipmentToMaterial] FOREIGN KEY ([IdMaterial]) REFERENCES [Material] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [MaterailEquipmentToEquipment] FOREIGN KEY ([IdEquipment]) REFERENCES [Equipment] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [CheckMeterialEquipmentCount] CHECK ([Count] > 0)
);
```

---

**CodeFirst:**

```
[Table("MaterialEquipment")]
public class MaterialEquipment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdMaterial { get; set; }
    public int IdEquipment { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipment { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Material> Material { get; set; }
}
```

Метод из класса унаследованного от `DbContext`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Material>()
                .HasMany(e => e.MaterialEquipment)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Material)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.IdMaterial)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Equipment>()
                .HasMany(e => e.MaterialEquipment)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Equipment)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.IdEquipment)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, это конечно работает. Но! при создании промежуточной таблицы вручную, получается очень громоздкий код по работе с нею, так же куча ошибок и неожиданных моментов. Может быть есть какое то решение пусть даже без столбца Count, чтобы все работало автоматически?

Comment: Подчерпнул информации отсюда http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table стало получше, но так как я использую общий контекст (generic) public DbSet<T> Objects { get; set; }, то пришлось создавать отдельный контекст лишь для этих трех таблиц что не есть хорошо!!! Спасибо за наводку, очень помогло!

Comment: @ArtemHohryakov, посмотрите метод Include в EF и паттерн Repository